# Mongoimport not adding JSON documents to db after import

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

mongoimport command returns with the correct amount of documents, and adds a new collection but when I try to open my db there is nothing. I am using a json array to store my data but am not sure why this isnt working.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport --db playerList --collection data --jsonArray --file ../../../../../nodeProjects/public/data.json
2016-07-20T09:30:05.807-0700    connected to: localhost
2016-07-20T09:30:05.813-0700    imported 1 document

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: test
> use playerList
switched to db playerList
> db.playerList.find().pretty()
> db.getCollectionNames()
[ "data" ]
```

and my data.json file is.

```
[{"name":"A.J. Green","team":"CIN","pos":"WR","weeklyPts":[{"week":1,"pts":6.3},{"week":2,"pts":10.5},{"week":3,"pts":34.7}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your collection is data not playerList which can be viewed in last line i.e `db.getCollectionNames()`, change `db.playerList.find().pretty` to `db.data.find.pretty()`and it will work

Answer (score 1):

The collection name in your find() is wrong, you are doing a find on the playerList collection but you imported the data into a collection called "data". So try:

```
db.data.find().pretty()
```